# Use $geoWithin operator in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Currently in a project I am using a query to find everything in a collection within x number of miles.  Reading of the mongodb docs it states that the $within operator is deprecated and that you should use the $geoWithin query operator.

I am using the Mongodb query builder (see below)

```
Query<Stuff>.WithinCircle(x => x.LongLat, longitude, latitude, radians, true)
```

and I am noticing that the query it creates uses the $within operator and not the $geoWithin operator.   I am not seeing any way to update it to use the correct operator as we have upgraded to Mongodb 2.4.x

Comment: FYI - I just saw that one too & filed an 'improvement' at mongodb's jira system: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about MongoDB, but it seems the mongodb-csharp code is not yet updated to use `$geoWithin`, as you can see here:

[mongo-csharp-driver (QueryBuilder)](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/MongoDB.Driver/Builders/QueryBuilder.cs)

```
public static IMongoQuery WithinCircle(string name, double centerX, double centerY, double radius, bool spherical)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }

    var shape = spherical ? "$centerSphere" : "$center";
    var condition = new BsonDocument("$within", new BsonDocument(shape, new BsonArray { new BsonArray { centerX, centerY }, radius }));
    return new QueryDocument(name, condition);
}
```

See, it uses `$within`.

Since the library is open source, you could fork, edit, and recompile it, and use your own version. Additionally, you could make a pull request to propose your changes to be included in the main code.

I think there is no "easier" way to do it, I hope this helps.